# Travel to Netherlands together with non-EU spouse

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, netherlands

Is it possible to travel to the Netherlands without the Schengen visa, my non-EU wife and myself UK/EU citizen? It's just for a 3 day trip.

Instead using UK issued marriage certificate, non-EU spouse's British Visa Card (which states it is a spouse visa) and husband's British Passport?

The Netherlands use VFS Global for Schengen visa processing and they do not appear to have appointments for the next 3 months, or their online booking system is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to travel to the Netherlands without the Schengen visa, my non-EU wife and myself UK/EU citizen? It's just for a 3 day trip.

Regardless of the length of the trip, it is only possible if your wife has a "residence card of a family member of an EU citizen."  She will not normally have this unless you live in some EU country other than the UK, or if you lived together elsewhere in the EU before moving to the UK.  Normally, the spouse of a UK citizen living in the UK or outside the EU won't have this.

> Instead using UK issued marriage certificate, non-EU spouse's British Visa Card (which states it is a spouse visa) and husband's British Passport?

I don't know what you mean by "British visa card," but it is almost certainly *not* the required "residence card of a family member of an EU citizen."

> The Netherlands use VFS Global for Schengen visa processing and they do not appear to have appointments for the next 3 months, or their online booking system is broken.

As the family member of an EU citizen, your wife should be able to apply for her visa directly at the consulate, so as to avoid VFS Global's processing fees, because the visa is supposed to be free of charge.  Information is available at the [VFS site for UK applications](https://www.vfsglobal.com/Netherlands/UK/visa-services/eea-eu-spouse.html), though they don't mention the option of applying without using their services.  This could mean that the Dutch government covers the service fee for these applications, in which case you won't likely be able to get through to the consulate.

However, you still should be able to, because the visa application process is supposed to be simplified and quick.  If you're unable to make an appointment at VFS, that should also justify an application at the consulate or embassy.  If you live in the UK, you can try [getting in touch with the Dutch Embassy in London](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/countries/united-kingdom/about-us/embassy-in-london).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why inaccurate information is being disseminated, ultimately discouraging individuals from asserting their legal rights.

According to Article 5(2) of Directive 2004/38:

> 2. Family members who are not nationals of a Member State shall only be required to have an entry visa in accordance with Regulation (EC)
>    No 539/2001 or, where appropriate, with national law. For the purposes
>    of this Directive, possession of the valid residence card referred to
>    in Article 10 shall exempt such family members from the visa
>    requirement. Member States shall **grant such persons every facility
>    to obtain the necessary visas**. Such visas shall be issued free of
>    charge **as soon as possible and on the basis of an accelerated
>    procedure**.

This provision already makes it clear that a 3-month waiting period for an EU family member to obtain a visa is inconsistent with the Directive. Moreover, Article 5(4) further clarifies that as long as an EU family member is traveling with, or intending to join, the EU citizen, they cannot be turned away at the border, provided their family ties can be verified (e.g., through a marriage certificate):

> 4. Where a Union citizen, or a family member who is not a national of a Member State, does not have the necessary travel documents or, if
>    required, the necessary visas, the Member State concerned shall,
>    before turning them back, give such persons every reasonable
>    opportunity to obtain the necessary documents or have them brought to
>    them within a reasonable period of time or to **corroborate or prove
>    by other means that they are covered by the right of free movement and
>    residence**

Article 6 of the Directive specifies that the EU family member is protected by the right of free movement and residence:

> Right of residence for up to three months
>
> 1. Union citizens shall have the **right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of up to three months without any
>    conditions or any formalities other than the requirement to hold a
>    valid identity card or passport**.
> 2. The provisions of paragraph 1 shall **also apply to family members in possession of a valid passport** who are not nationals of a Member
>    State, **accompanying or joining the Union citizen**.

Finally, the European Court of Justice of the European Union, in its landmark decision C-459/99 MRAX v État belge (which inter alia interprets the notion of "every facility to obtain the necessary visas"), unequivocally stated at paragraphs 60 and 61 that EU family members of any nationality can cross EU borders without a prior visa requirement. Such visas must be issued at the point of entry, and it is categorically forbidden to reject such family members:

> 60 However, Article 3(2) of Directive 68/360 and Article 3(2) of
> Directive 73/148 state that the Member States are to accord to such
> persons **every facility for obtaining any necessary visas**. This
> means that, if those provisions of Directives 68/360 and 73/148 are
> **not to be denied their full effect, a visa must be issued without delay and, as far as possible, at the place of entry into national
> territory**.
>
> 61 In view of the importance which the Community legislature has
> attached to the **protection of family life** (see paragraph 53 of
> this judgment), it is in any event disproportionate and, therefore,
> **prohibited to send back a third country national married to a national of a Member State where he is able to prove his identity and
> the conjugal ties** and there is no evidence to establish that he
> represents a risk to the requirements of public policy, public
> security or public health within the meaning of Article 10 of
> Directive 68/360 and Article 8 of Directive 73/148.
>
> 62 The answer to the first question referred for a preliminary ruling
> must therefore be that, on a proper construction of Article 3 of
> Directive 68/360, Article 3 of Directive 73/148 and Regulation No
> 2317/95, read in the light of the principle of proportionality, a
> Member State may not send back at the border a third country national
> who is married to a national of a Member State and attempts to enter
> its territory without being in possession of a valid identity card or
> passport or, if necessary, a visa, where he is able to prove his
> identity and the conjugal ties and there is no evidence to establish
> that he represents a risk to the requirements of public policy, public
> security or public health within the meaning of Article 10 of
> Directive 68/360 and Article 8 of Directive 73/148.

Any practices by Member States that deviate from these guidelines are not only in violation of the Directive but also contradict a crucial CJEU ruling.

I hope this clarifies matters. I would also encourage EU families to file complaints with both national and EU authorities for continued lack of proper application of the EU law and blatant violations of the fundamental right to the protection of family life.

Comment: "Such visas must be issued at the point of entry, and it is categorically forbidden to reject such family members": but they're not going to be able to reach the port of entry if an airline or ferry operator doesn't allow them to board because they don't have a visa.

Comment: if the airline or ferry operator does so, it is in violation of EU law and can be liable for damages. This would be a direct violation of a CJEU decision! You must present to the ferry operator or airline your marriage certificate and travel with a copy of the CJEU decision. See also the Raducan case in the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: "if the airline or ferry operator does so, it is in violation of EU law and can be liable for damages": which EU law?  Certainly not article 5(2), which provides that version family members are required to have a visa.  "This would be a direct violation of a CJEU decision": which CJEU decision requires carriers to ignore article 5(2)?  _Raducan_ concerns the actions of a member state, not of a carrier.  Regarding the first sentence of this answer, what "inaccurate information is being disseminated"?

Comment: This is how the CJEU construes the notion of "every facility" in Article 5(2): 60 However, Article 3(2) of Directive 68/360 and Article 3(2) of Directive 73/148 state that the Member States are to accord to such persons every facility for obtaining any necessary visas. This means that, if those provisions of Directives 68/360 and 73/148 are not to be denied their full effect, a visa must be issued without delay and, as far as possible, at the place of entry into national territory.

Comment: But the "every facility" requirement is directed toward states, not transportation providers.  Thinking about the reason for the visa requirement in the first place, which is on the surface rather odd if not contrary to the principle of free movement, it seems that the most likely reason for imposing it is to avoid putting airlines in the position of having to evaluate marriage certificates and other non-secure documents showing family ties. I'm unaware of a court ruling requiring airlines to do so.  So, once again, in most cases it will be difficult or impossible to _reach_ a place of entry.

Comment: I understand your perspective; however, the MRAX obligation is rooted in the protection of the fundamental right to protect family life, as articulated in the Charter. This obligation is directly enforceable and imposes duties not only on states but also on private entities. If the family ties in question are genuine, preventing an EU family from embarking would constitute a violation of this right. This could potentially make carriers liable for such violations, especially if you have provided a marriage certificate duly authenticated and translated into English at the very least.

Comment: Given that carriers are not in a position to accurately assess the validity of these documents, they also lack the authority to reject them outright. Thus, carriers may actually have an incentive to allow you to embark if you present proper documentation and adequately explain the scope of your rights. This way, the responsibility for verifying the authenticity of the family ties shifts to border control at the port of entry, rather than resting with the carriers themselves.

Comment: The obligation is directly enforceable on states.  I see nothing in the public record supporting the assertion that an airline refusing to transport someone without a visa violates EU law.  The problem is that the carrier can be liable for a fine of several thousand euros for transporting someone without adequate documents, and the EU legislature has obviously come to the conclusion that this isn't a burden airlines should be saddled with.  As I said in my answer, the solution here is to pursue the Dutch consulate to get a visa quickly, not to try to travel without one.

Comment: To the extent that this legal theory may be correct, it is certainly not recognized as such by any Schengen state, as a quick look at TIMATIC will show.  Since airlines follow TIMATIC, the only way to put this theory into effect will be for an Annex I national to attempt to fly under the free movement directive without a visa.  Boarding will certainly be denied, whereafter a court action could be undertaken.  I don't see any evidence that anyone has sued on these grounds, but I don't have access to specialized search tools.  Regardless, it's not a practical solution for an actual visit.

Comment: Also as a practical matter, the proposition that carriers "lack the authority to reject" proof of relationship is unworkable.  If such a principle were put in place then anyone would be able to fly to the EU without a visa by showing a fake marriage certificate and claiming that they are traveling to join the spouse indicated on it.  Yes, these people would be rejected at the border -- unless they made an asylum claim, which is one of the things the visa policy seeks to limit.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your argument. The fundamental right to protect family life, as outlined in paragraphs 60-62 of the MRAX decision, is non-negotiable and must be upheld by carriers. They don't have the discretion to choose whether to respect this right. While it's true that irregularities must be prevented, this cannot serve as a justification for infringing upon the rights of genuine EU families. The responsibility for verifying familial ties should fall on duly authorized governmental officials, not on the carriers themselves.

Comment: If carriers take it upon themselves to prevent EU families from boarding, they expose themselves to legal liability. Arguing otherwise would render the MRAX decision effectively irrelevant and unenforceable, which is an untenable conclusion.